# AJAX broken, POST route 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I've been working on this for a couple of days. I'm certain its something really stupid, but I'm at the end of my sanity.

The public files are set up properly.

Error Message:

```
POST 127.0.0.1:8080/api/pvtToggle 404 (Not Found)
```

Front End HTML:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Heating:</strong> {{#if heating}} {{this.heating}} {{else}} N/A {{/if}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Cooling:</strong> {{#if cooling}} {{this.cooling}} {{else}} N/A {{/if}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="checkbox" id="pvt{{this.id}}" checked="{{this.private}}" onchange="togDefine({{this.id}}, {{this.private}});" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Private" data-off="Public" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" />
     </div>
   </div>
```

AJAX Call:

```
//  Private-Public toggle
let togDefine = (id, pvt) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/pvtToggle",
    data: {
      id: id,
      newState: (pvt === 'true') ? false : true
    },
    success: function(text) {
      if (text === 'ok') {
        pvtSuccess(id, pvt);
      } else {
        console.log('updatePvt failed');
      }
    }
  });

};


let pvtSuccess = (id, pvt) => {
  $('#pvt' + id).attr('checked', (pvt === 'true') ? 'false' : 'true');
};
```

Back End:

```
//TOGGLE Private vs Public PROPERTY
app.put('/api/pvtToggle/', isAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
  db.Prop.update({
    private: request.params.newState
  }, {
    where: {
      id: request.params.id
    }
  }).then(data => {
    response.send('ok');
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});
```

Please help me figure out why the request isn't working properly. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint is `app.put`, implying it responds to a PUT request,

but your ajax/fetches are making POST requests.

Comment: @zkidi Thank you for that. I have method-override installed, but since I'm not actually submitting a form here and didn't define the put in the action I guess I just dropped the ball on this. It's been a while since I did this stuff, so I'm making lots of weird mistakes.